# xml.etree.ElementTree parse - AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: xml, python-3.x, xml.etree

Help with parsing. I have a file and I want to get an ID.
When i try use  get('')  on xml.etree.ElementTree parse, I have Error:

> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get'

My code is:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('sample.xml')   
root = tree.getroot()

for elem in root:

    print(elem.findall('alarmTime').get('id'))
```

My XML file  is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<zAppointments reminder="15">
    <appointment>
        <begin>1181251680</begin>
        <uid>040000008200E000</uid>
            <alarmTime id ='MAIN'>MONDAY</alarmTime>
                <STOP id='091'> OK </STOP>
                <DEF> NO </DEF>      
        <state></state>
        <location></location>
        <duration>1800</duration>
        <subject>Bring pizza home</subject>
    </appointment>
    <appointment>
        <begin>1234360800</begin>
        <duration>1800</duration>
            <subject>Check MS Office website for updates</subject>
            <location></location>
        <uid>604f4792-eb89-478b-a14f-dd34d3cc6c21-1234360800</uid>
        <state>dismissed</state>
    </appointment>
    <appointment>
        <begin>1181251680</begin>
        <uid>040000008200E000</uid>
            <alarmTime id ='SECOND'>SUNDAY</alarmTime>
                <STOP id='092'> OK-1 </STOP>
                <DEF> NO-1 </DEF>      
        <state></state>
        <location></location>
        <duration>1800</duration>
        <subject>Bring pizza home</subject>
    </appointment>
</zAppointments>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`findall` returns a list so you can't use `get` method on it. If you are sure that alarmTime exists in every node of xml then use the code below

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('sample.xml')   
root = tree.getroot()

for elem in root:

    print(elem.findall('alarmTime')[0].get('id'))
```

Another possible solution is to use `find` function but it will throw error if it can't find `alarmTime` in element node

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('sample.xml')   
root = tree.getroot()

for elem in root:

    print(elem.find('alarmTime').get('id'))
```